# Custom dialog or custom activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I want to use user conformations many times in my app. Like "You're about to do 'this', or 'that'. Are you ok ?" with yes/no buttons, or "Tip : do 'this' or 'that'" with a `checkbox` to 'don't show again'.

What is the better way to do this ? Should I use an `activity` with some parameters to specify the kind of popup I want ? And use `startActivityForResult` to get the results. Or create a `customdialog` class ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should use dialog to accept user confirmation.

Comment: check here..... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Its better to use a custom dialog class.

Comment: @user2408608 custom dialog is easy as well as best to use.

Comment: You certainly should use a dialog.  Depending on complexities, you may want to use DialogFragments and reuse them in your dialogs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I use the android `Dialog` but I use a custom layout for that match the design of my application.

Here is an example:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_delete_contact, null))
.setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(android.R.string.ok).toUpperCase(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // YOUR TREATMENT
    }
})
.setNegativeButton(context.getResources().getString(android.R.string.cancel).toUpperCase(), null)
.show();
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/GrayLight"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/remove_contact"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/ask_remove_contact"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Result in picture:

[image]

To avoid rewriting the code every time here is a utility class :

```
public class MyDialog {

public static Builder create(final Context context, final LayoutInflater layoutInflater, final String title, final String content) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.generic_dialog, null);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitleDialog)).setText(title);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewContentDialog)).setText(content);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setView(view);
}

}
```

And an example of using :

```
AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = MyDialog.create(this, getLayoutInflater(), "Quitter ECOLEMS", "Voulez-vous vraiment quitter l'application?");
myDialog.setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // YOUR TREATMENT
    }
})
.setNegativeButton("Non", null)
.show();
```

I hope you have helped!

Comment: Thank you. Is there any solution to not rewrite the code around the treatment every time I use this ?

Comment: Yes it is possible by creating a utility class. I'll add in my answer.

Comment: @lopez.mikhael when I try your code it says : `getLayoutInflater(Bundle) in Fragment cannot be applied to ()`, how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html).
It has built-in functionality to allow yes/no choices.
If you extend it, you can add your functionality to "Don't show this again"

Answer (score 0):

Any Its better to use `Dialog` however for this purpose you will have more controls on `Dialog` than `Activity`.